# Getting InvalidPdfException while reading pdf containing form like structure using iTextSharp library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I am trying to extract text from pdf file using iTextSharp library. It works fine for pdf files which has simple plain text but for files which has some form like structure in first few pages of pdf it gives InvalidPDFException.

> {"Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: xref subsection not found at file pointer 20"}

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader("D:\\Finra PDF\\SR-FINRA-2015-058.pdf")
```

Above is the line where the exception occurs. I also attach the image of first page of pdf which has readonly form. [image: PDF with first two pages having form like structure]

[Please click here for PDF Doc](http://www.finra.org/sites/default/files/SR-FINRA-2016-004.pdf)

Please let me know is this the limitation of iTextSharp library. If so is there any open source library available which can process pdf document which has rich formatting like this one. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to provide the PDF so that we can inspect it. This is probably not a limitation in iText, but an invalid structure in your PDF.

Comment: Look like a corrupt PDF, nothing to do with text extraction. You'll have to show us the PDF.

Comment: Hi Michael / Paulo  I have edited my post & added PDF link there. To view & download the pdf click on "Please click here for PDF Doc" link in the above post

Comment: @VJGaur I just tried to open your document in a `PdfReader` and it worked without a problem. I used iTextSharp 5.5.9.

Comment: I am also using the same version of iTextSharp but it's giving me InvalidPDF exception in a very first line of the code as mentioned in post. I do not know why it's giving exception for this particular pdf else it works fine for other pdfs.  Am i doing anything wrong ? I am wondering

Comment: MK i got the problem when i use the web link path of pdf it worked fine. I was able to extract the text. What i was doing earlier is i was downloading & storing these pdf in one folder frm where i was reading it there it failed loading it but other files in the same folder is working perfectly leaving this one. Thanks